# vlookup data from another work book as per list of sheets name

Tags: vlookup

I have 2 Excel workbook and the first contains one sheet with list of name.

This name is related to another excel workbook sheets name.

How can I use `vlookup` to get access to tablearray tese many sheets and get data into first excel sheet as per sheet name?